# In pattern matching, can I use the matched pattern as is?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

```
case first :: rest => first match {
      case Heading(_,_) => buildPairsAcc(rest, acc, ???)
      case Paragraph(_) // ... other cases
```

Instead of the **???** I'd like to use the matched `Heading` object. Can it be done without repeating the constructor, or do I need a different construct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use the heading itself on `???`'s place, this can be done using the `@` pattern:

```
case first :: rest => first match {
      case head @ Heading(_,_) => buildPairsAcc(rest, acc, head)
      case Paragraph(_) // ... other cases
```

Note that this can be used on everything that'll pattern match, including lists:

```
case lst @ head::tail => // do stuff with lst head and tail
```